# Superscript in brackets for my axis title

Tags: r, plot, brackets, subscript, superscript

I made a boxplot with `boxplot()` and I have a superscript in my y-lab labeling.
It looks like this:
`ylab = expression(paste("spleen volume cm"^3))`

Now I want the "cm3" with the superscript of "3" in brackets [cm^3].

I tried this:

```
ylab = expression("spleen volume " (paste("[cm"^3, "]")))
```

but unfortunately the whole thing is in () too, how can i remove these "()" around it? [here is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hud2.png)

Unfortunately I am failing, can anyone help?

Kind regards!

Comment: Do you mean `expression(paste("spleen volume [cm]"^3)` Or `expression(paste("spleen volume cm", '[^3]'))` ?

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah. 
I mean the cm3 must be in brackets and the "3" must be a superscript. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Alexander-P look at the code RonakShah is proposing you. Parentheses are located differently than in your code and thus they will throw different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
xlab = expression(paste("spleen volume [cm"^3, "]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The solution posted by Ronak should work. Or did you also want the `^3` in the brackets?

```r
plot(runif(10),runif(10),xlab = expression(paste("spleen volume [cm]"^3)))
```

If so, you can use the following code:

```r
plot(runif(10),runif(10),xlab = as.expression(bquote("Spleen volume [" ~ cm^3 ~ "]")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: As this answer is based on Ronaks comment, please award him with the answer. This is posted as an answer to allow for use of Reprex to show that it works.

Comment: Thank you @mhh. Yes i need the ^3 in the brackets. Can you do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a solution that has what you want

Comment: Why to use both `as.expression()` and `bquote()`? `expression()` is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help @mhh. 

This is nearly perfect. Is there any way to remove the space between "[" and "cm" and between "3" and "]"?

Comment: Just remove the space between and after the `~`, @Alexander-P.

Comment: @mhh `~` represents space in `plotmath` syntax. Removing the space between and after the `~` makes no sense because `~` still exist.