# R ggarrange how to include upper scripts in the plot titles?

Tags: r, label, expression

I am trying to add plot labels as titles in plots merged by `ggarrange`. My label contains parantheses and substricpts. I have found that using `expression('My volume [m'^3*'/ha]')` I can handle both, which works perfectly if placed as x or y label (`ylab(expression('My volume [m'^3*'/ha]'))`).

However, when using the same approach using `ggarrange` to combine different plots, and wishing to name them `a)` and `b)`, the naming prints quotes as well:

[image]

How can I correctly write the expression, or using `paste('..', '..')` approach that quotes are not visible?

Dummy example to create several plots and plot them using `ggarrange`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() 
p2 <- p1
  
ggarrange(p1, p2, 
          nrow = 2, ncol = 1,  
          common.legend = TRUE,
          legend="bottom",
          labels=list(paste("a) ", 'My rate [%]'),
                     paste('b)', expression('My volume [m'^3*'/ha]'))), # How to change this???
          align = c("hv"),
          font.label = list(size = 10, 
                            face = "plain", 
                            color ="black"))
```

Wrong labeled output b:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found my answer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257415/superscript-in-brackets-for-my-axis-title). This works when replacing titles, but I bet it would work for `ggarrange` as well. Important it that it works with paranteses and a superscript.

```
p1 +  ggtitle(expression(paste("a) ", "volume [m"^3, "/ha", "]")))
```

[image]